# MQTT:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to use SSL with MQTT and gets following error,

```
1379677998: Client connection from 127.0.0.1 failed: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
1379678058: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure
1379678058: Socket read error on client (null), disconnecting.
```

My conf file has seetings as below,

```
port 8883
cafile /home/administrator/Downloads/mosquitto-1.2.1_dilip/test/ssl/test-root-ca.crt (also tried all-ca.crt here)
certfile /home/administrator/Downloads/mosquitto-1.2.1_dilip/test/ssl/server.crt
keyfile /home/administrator/Downloads/mosquitto-1.2.1_dilip/test/ssl/server.key
tls_version tlsv1
require_certificate true (tried commenting this too)
```

and I run,  08-ssl-connect-cert-auth.test from test folder. code snippet included below

```
    mosquitto_tls_opts_set(mosq, 1, "tlsv1", NULL);
    mosquitto_tls_set(mosq, "../ssl/test-root-ca.crt", "../ssl/certs", "../ssl/client.crt", "../ssl/client.key", NULL);
    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq, on_connect);
    mosquitto_disconnect_callback_set(mosq, on_disconnect);

    rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, "localhost", 8883, 60);
```

Environment info:

```
Python 2.7.3
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.0
mosquitto-1.2.1/mosquitto-1.2
```

Please let me know what could go wrong here? I also tried generating certificates using gen.sh.

Thanks in advance.

-Dilip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a general note - you should be generating your own certificates, don't use the ones provided by mosquitto for testing, or use the gen.sh script without modifying it for your own details.

To use the certificates provided, you should be using `all-ca.crt` in the broker. It contains the example root CA and intermediary CA certificates. The client only requires the root CA for verification purposes.

You are using a full path to the certificates in the broker configuration, but relative paths in the client. Are you sure that they are both correct?

Have you tried running the tests unmodified with `make test`? This would tell you if there is a problem with your openssl installation for example.

Comment: Thanks Roger for your prompt response.

We have tried on a fresh version(1.2.1) of broker with unmodified test suit and it seems to be working fine now with a small changes on the cert paths in "08-ssl-connect-cert-auth.c"(i.e. one level up).

mosquitto_tls_set(mosq, "../../ssl/test-root-ca.crt", "../../ssl/certs", "../../ssl/client.crt", "../../ssl/client.key", NULL);

BTW, we are just curious to know what is "../../ssl/certs" pointing to, as we can't see any certs folder inside ssl folder ?

Comment: You're right, it's unused in those tests. It does allow you to use a directory of certificates if needed.